# Reusing an UIView that was set as inputAccessoryView earlier, doesnt seem to work

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

My ViewController contains

1. a UITextView and
2. a simple UIView variable called bar.

In textViewShouldBeginEditing() I remove bar from the ViewController's View and set it as textView's inputAccessoryView :

```
bar.removeFromSuperview()
textView.inputAccessoryView = bar
textView.reloadInputViews()
```

This works as expected.
Later when I call endEditing  i remove bar from the TextView's inputAccessoryView and pit it back to ViewController's View, like this:

```
textView.inputAccessoryView = nil
textView.reloadInputViews()
bar.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:500,width:100,height:50)
view.addSubview(bar)
```

But bar does not appear back on the ViewController's view. Here is the dump of bar at the end of the process when it not appearing on the screen:

---

```
bar.window:  Optional(<UIWindow: 0x7faa79608d50; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000048fa0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x600000036f20>>)

bar.superview:  Optional(<UIView: 0x7faa794141c0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x60800023a800>>)

dump(bar): 
▿ Optional(<UIView: 0x7faa7940faf0; frame = (0 500; 100 50); layer = <CALayer: 0x608000037940>>)
  - some: <UIView: 0x7faa7940faf0; frame = (0 500; 100 50); layer = <CALayer: 0x608000037940>> #0
    - super: UIResponder
      - super: NSObject
```

---

Where am I going wrong?

here is the code of my viewcontroller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        bar = UIView()
        bar.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:500,width:100,height:50)
        bar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        //setToolBar()
        textView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    var bar: UIView!


    func setToolBar() {
        bar.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:500,width:100,height:50)
        view.addSubview(bar)
        textView.inputAccessoryView = nil
        textView.reloadInputViews()


        print("-----------------------\n");
        print("cust.window: ", bar.window)
        print("cust.superview: ", bar.superview)
        print("dump: ")
        dump(bar)
        print("\n-----------------------\n")
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        print("ABOUT TO SET TOOLBAR ")
        setToolBar()
        print("JUST SET TOOLBAR ")
    }


    func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        bar.removeFromSuperview()
        print("here")
        dump(bar)
        textView.inputAccessoryView = bar
        textView.reloadInputViews()
        return true
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if(text == "\n") {
            print("FRAME:", bar.frame)
            //textView.inputAccessoryView = nil
            //textView.inputView = nil
            //textView.reloadInputViews()

            dismissKeyboard()

            return false
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: doesnt seem to be happening any more on ios 11. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By setting `inputAccessoryView` to nil, you're deallocating the view and it no longer exists when you try to reuse it. Try adding it as a subview first and then setting the `inputAccessoryView` to nil.

Comment: I am not sure that the view (bar) is getting deallocated because I can call dump on it at the moment it is not visible on screen. Also the view (bar) appears on the accessoryView the next time I click on the textView. It is only when the keyboard is collapsed the view (bar) disappears. Also it is referenced in the Viewcontroller code by a variable named bar. I tried what u suggested but no change in observations